# Mono.fromCallable executing on calling thread by default?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm attempting to perform an asynchronous operation using Project Reactor's `Mono.fromCallable(Callable)` and I noticed that, in my test case, it appears to be running on the calling thread. Is it documented somewhere that `Mono.fromCallable(Callable)` uses the calling thread by default?

I see from the [Reactor reference guide best practices](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) I should do something like the following:

```java
Mono blockingWrapper = Mono.fromCallable(() -> { 
    return /* make a remote synchronous call */ 
});
blockingWrapper = blockingWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

But I don't see anywhere that `Schedulers.immediate()` is used by default. Why not default to `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`?

Comment: It's not just `fromCallable`, but Reactor pipelines in general, that are executed on the calling thread (main) by default. There are only a couple of operators (like delay) which change that: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers
Also, elastic thread pool is not the best fir for reactive programming so should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Also important to note that you use Mono.fromCallable to wrap your blocking call, but it's not its only use case, so it wouldn't be 'fair' to always execute it on the elastic thread pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Threading and Schedulers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers) section of the reactor user guide is relevant to your question (emphasis mine):

> Obtaining a `Flux` or a `Mono` does not necessarily mean that it runs in a dedicated Thread. Instead, most operators continue working in the Thread on which the previous operator executed. **Unless specified, the topmost operator (the source) itself runs on the Thread in which the `subscribe()` call was made.**

The `.subscribeOn(...)` operator will cause the upstream `Callable` to be invoked on the specified Scheduler, instead of the Thread on which the `subscribe()` call was made.

The `Callable` passed to `.fromCallable` does not run on another Scheduler by default, because all `Callable`s do not necessarily block.  Therefore, in a lot of cases, there's no reason to execute the `Callable` on another Scheduler.